# Handling D templated structs as a common type

Tags: templates, d

I'm in trouble on designing a D app. Maybe my approach is completely wrong, so I come here to you rescue me. Any suggestion, including complete rewrite, is welcome.

I have some templated types:

```
enum Type : byte { Message='!', Integer='@' }

struct Token (T) {
    Type type;
    T value;
}

alias Token!string MessageToken;
alias Token!long   IntegerToken;
```

And I need to handle these types generically:

```
AnyToken genToken(bool cond) {
  if (cond)
     return MessageToken(Type.Message, "nighly builds");
  else
      return IntegerToken(Type.Integer, -42);
}

AnyToken a = genToken(true);
AnyToken b = genToken(false);
```

How do I achieve this effect? **Edit:** OOP alternatives are welcome too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have used a tagged union myself

```
struct Token{
    Type type;
    union{
        string str;
        long integer;
    }
    @property string strMessage()in{assert(type==Type.Message)}body{
        return str;
    }
    @property void strMessage(string s){
        type=Type.Message;
        str=s;
    }
    @property long intMessage()in{assert(type==Type.Integer)}body{
        return integer;
    }
    @property void intMessage(long l){
        type=Type.Integer;
        integer=l;
    }
}
```

note that there's no static (compile time) difference between them but it's pretty much the best on can do without inheritance

you can add some extra functions so it looks more like inheritance so you won't need to examine the type field so much outside the struct's functions

Comment: How can I add functions for it looks more like inheritance? Less examinations will be better. I like the way you infer the type from argument, fits well here.

Comment: inside the function you can do the `final switch(type){case Type.Integer:...case Type.Message:...}` deal in the function. I meant that (most of) those checks would be centered inside the definition of the struct so that when you would want to add a type you won't have to hunt them all down

Comment: Thanks, now i'm using `final switch` for it.

Comment: I changed `struct` by `class` for copies occur by reference. Token is small enough to be a struct? Nothing for nothing? What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

You could use std.variant.

I can't imagine another way. In the end they are completely separate types.

Comment: Would I have some advantage in using `std.variant` instead of constructing my own tagged union?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to keep the original structs then you could create a hierarchy of classes that wrap a pointer to a struct and dispatch accordingly.

Comment: No, I don't need to keep the structs. What about a class hierarchy wrapping a protected union? There will be _many_ small tokens with few or zero copies.